# javascript random quote generator not printing

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to generate a fresh quote from a list on every refresh. For some reason, I can't get the quotes to show up within the div, and I'm not sure why.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
<div id="quotes">

<script>
var quotes = new Array();
quotes[0] = "<i>Quote 1</i><br><b>Author</b>";
quotes[1] = "<i>Quote 2</i><br><b>Author</b>";

var random = Math.ceil (Math.random() * quotes.length) - 1;
$('quotes').set('html', quotes[random]);
</script>

</div>
```

I've updated my code thanks to everyones help to this-

```
<div id="quotes"></div>

<script>
var quotes = [
"<i>"Some people feel the rain. Others just get wet."</i><br><b>Bob Marley/b>",
"<i>“Do not pray for an easy life, pray for the strength to endure a                    difficult one.”</i><br><b>Bruce Lee</b>",
"<i>“Success is not final, failure is not fatal: it is the courage to continue that counts.”</i><br><b>Winston
Churchill</b>",
"<i>If your dreams don’t scare you they’re not big enough.</i><br><b></b>",
"<i>“It takes courage to grow up and become who you really are.”</i><br><b>E.E. Cummings</b>",
"<i>All endings are also beginnings, we just don’t know it yet.</i><br><b></b>",
"<i>There are three kinds of people: Those who make it happen, those who watch it happen, and
those who wonder what the heck happened.</i><br><b></b>",
"<i>There are people so poor, that the only thing they have is money.</i><br><b></b>",
"<i>“Things do not happen. Things are made to happen.”</i><br><b>John F. Kennedy</b>",
"<i>“Destiny is a name often given in retrospect to choices that had dramatic consequences.”</i><br><b>J.K. Rowling</b>",
"<i>“When I was 5 years old, my mother always told me that happiness was the key to life.
When I went to school, they asked me what I wanted to be when I grew up. I wrote
down ‘happy’. They told me I didn’t understand the assignment, and I told them they didn’t
understand life.”</i><br><b>John Lennon</b>",
"<i>“Not all those who wander are lost”</i><br><b>JRR Tolkien</b>",
"<i>We all die. The goal isn’t to live forever, the goal is to create something that will.</i><br><b></b>",
"<i>Strive for progress, not perfection.</i><br><b></b>",
"<i>What defines us is how well we rise after falling.</i><br><b></b>",
"<i>“It’s not hard to make decisions once you know what your values are.”</i><br><b>Roy E. Disney</b>",
"<i>Sorry’s not good enough.</i><br><b></b>",
"<i>I may not be there yet, but I’m closer than I was yesterday.
Every day is a new beginning. Stay away from what might have been and look at what can
be.</i><br><b></b>",
"<i>Who inspires you?</i><br><b></b>",
"<i>“If you play by the rules long enough, then you can change the game.”</i><br><b>Enders Game</b>"
];

document.getElementById('quotes').innerHTML = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)];
</script>
```

For some reason, the div is still loading without any content thought.

It was the quotes inside of my quotes messing it up. Thank you everyone for the help!!

Comment: The script to update with a random quote is itself inside the "quotes" div, so setting its `html` would overwrite the script. Also, since it's an inline script, it will execute as the DOM is loading, and it tries to update the `html` before it's "ready" in the DOM (i.e. closing div tag not reached yet). Try moving the script to the bottom of the page or inside the framework's (MooTools ?) dom ready event.

Comment: @Bryan That doesn't matter, since once the script is loaded into memory you can even delete its `<script>` node and it'll still be running.

Comment: @Kolink, good point and thanks for the correction.

Comment: Every time I see someone using `new Array()` in JavaScript, [it hurts](https://coderwall.com/p/h4xm0w) me a little bit.

Answer (score 1):

Removing the need for any library makes the code a lot easier to not botch.

```
<div id="quotes"></div>
<script>
var quotes = [
    "<i>Quote 1</i><br><b>Author</b>",
    "<i>Quote 2</i><br><b>Author</b>"
];

document.getElementById('quotes').innerHTML =
                                   quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)];
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! I tried updating my code with your example, but for some reason my div is still loading blank

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** Nevermind, seems like `$` in MooTools should indeed return the element with the id `quotes`. If you wanted to do the same thing with no frameworks, you could use `document.getElementById('quotes').innerHTML = quotes[random]`.

Your `$` is trying to find an element called `<quotes>`, not an element with the id "quotes" (assuming that it uses CSS selectors like jQuery). Using `$('#quotes')` should fix it.

A few other things: You could write the array in a much more concise fashion:

```
quotes = [
  "<i>Quote 1</i><br><b>Author</b>",
  "<i>Quote 2</i><br><b>Author</b>"
];
```

Also, you could just use `Math.floor` instead of `Math.ceil` for your random value, then you wouldn't need the `- 1` at the end.

Comment: The syntax looks more like MooTools than jQuery.

Comment: Oh. Well, if it's using CSS selectors like jQuery, then #quotes should do the trick either way.

Comment: If indeed it is MooTools, the syntax is correct (if memory serves, though it has been awhile since I've needed to write any MT code :)).

Comment: Yeah, making assumptions is not a good idea. My own site's JS file defines `$` as a function that is run as if it were placed before the `</body>` tag, you can't just assume it means jQuery.

Comment: Seems like MooTools' $ should indeed return the div with the id "quotes", while $$ would be the CSS selector shorthand similar to jQuery's $.